# How to call a promise after execute some code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have this two line of code

```
checkInput.login(req, res);
database.login();
```

The second line is a function that contain a promise, I need to execute the second line after the first, how can I do that?

Comment: The second line **IS** executed after the first one.

Comment: Having no clue what login() is, it is basically impossible for us to answer. Does login return a promise? If use, than use `then`. Does login return something else? Again, we need more details.

Comment: First line doesn't return a promise but the second yes

Comment: @Pigna Well the first line needs to give some indication when it is done so ....

Answer (score 0):

Now, as the comment said it **IS** excuting one after another. But if two functions are promises (which I think based on the names) you have to use `.then()` or `async/await`

```
checkInput.login(req, res)
.then(()=>{
    return database.login();
})
.then(()=>{
    console.log('yay db logged in')
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.resolve(checkInput.login(req,res))
.then((response)=>{
 console.log(response);
 database.login();
});
```

I guess the checkInput.login function is also asynchrounous. Try this.